# crystal report library for visual studio 2008

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

I have an rpt file that was created usign crystal report version 8

is there a library that is available for vs2008 that can convert the rpt file results to a pdf file?

i tried to install crystal report runtime 2008 in windows 7 but it is not installing nor giving any errors

pls help

-Vivek

Comment: Vivek, this is the 3rd post of yours following up on the same problem... Try to amend your original post unless the problem relates to something different. This helps us to keep the site organised. Thanks very much

Comment: Hi Berdal. Sorry about that. Will do for my future questions. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use Crystal's Export function to save as .pdf?

Or are you looking for a programmatic way to do it?